# if is not null in query mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have multiple field and getting values from ajax method post and i want to filter table with this values.

my query in page.php:

```
$status=$_POST['status'];
$pname=$_POST['pname'];

$qr1 = $mysqli->query(
    "SELECT id,uid,status,pname
     FROM `tbl1`,`tbl2`
     WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL AND `uid`=21 "
);

if(!is_null($_POST['status'])) {
    $qr1 .= (" AND `status` = '$status' ");
}

if(!is_null($_POST['pname'])) {
    $qr1 .= (" AND `product_name`='$pname' ");
}

$row1=$qr1->fetch_object();
```

but return null and query was empty!
Where I was wrong??

Comment: Why don't you use parameters while already using mysqli?

Comment: Please read some documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp (you will be able to understand quickly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$qr1` is a result of query execution.
You should add clauses to query text, not to query result.

```
$q = "SELECT id,uid,status,pname
FROM `tbl1`,`tbl2`
WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL AND `uid`=21";
if(!is_null($_POST['status'])) {
    $q .= (" AND `status` = '$status' ");
}
if(!is_null($_POST['pname'])) {
    $q .= (" AND `product_name`='$pname' ");
}
$qr1 = $mysqli->query($q);
```

And of course - don't forget about sql-injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: when a field is null the query return empty, i want when one or more field is edit the query return value!

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the query directly by calling `$mysqli->query(...)`, the result is a result object of everything found in the database.

You are then adding strings to that result object. Problem is: The query has already been executed. You have to add strings to the query string before calling `query()`.